# How to fix when ipywidgets do not render in a jupyter-lab notbook?

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I have jupyter-lab version 3.6.3 installed and it fails to render ipywidgets. I followed the instructions mentioned in their [documentation](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.5/user_install.html) and it still does not render.

These are the steps I've taken:

```
conda install -n base -c conda-forge widgetsnbextension
conda install -n test_env -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

I run the `jupyter-lab` in the `base` env from the terminal and then select the `test_env` as for my kernel when the notebook loads. Then I run the following cell:

```py
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets as widgets

w = widgets.IntSlider()
display(w)
```

And it outputs:

```
IntSlider(value=0)
```

I have restarted the jupyter-lab process multiple times to make sure the changes are in effect. And still, no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else faced the same problem, these additional steps fixed the problem for me:

```
sudo jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix
```

And

```
sudo jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```